# How do I get a Play Game button on my page that is not created through the game?

Tags: facebook-page

when creating a community/fan page for a Game through the settings in the developer account, you have the option to add a "Play Game" button just below the title image of the page.

Creating a Page in any other way, you do not seem to have that option. Hence my problem:

We created our Community page and started generating likes and traffic to it, before creating a Game App in the developer tool. We have now launched our Game and want to have the "Play Game" button on the community page.

Is there any way of achieving this other than creating an entirely new page and asking people to move their likes there?

I have looked into Migrating the page, but that option does not seem to be available any more, and it is unclear whether it would work anyway. The other option is to just create the new page and ask people to like the new page instead. This would make us lose our vanity URL though, which we do not wish to lose...

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and have finally found a solution:

1. Go into your Page Settings (Edit Page -> Update Info).
2. Under category, choose "App Page".
3. Save changes.
4. Now go to your App settings.
5. Choose App Details.
6. (If you have submitted to App Center, cancel the submission).
7. Choose you page under "App Page".
8. Save changes.

Answer (score 0):

In FB developer settings, go to your app>advanced settings at the bottom there is a spot to create a community page. That page that you create will have the Play Button you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mathieu. I'm afraid this doesn't quite solve my problem though. I need to migrate an existing page, that has been created in a different way, to the page that has been created through app>advanced settings>community page.

Comment: John - were you able to find a solution?  I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's a been old question but the solution that is working nowadays is :

1. go to your facebook page,
2. Settings > Page Info
3. there you need to update your category and ONLY have "App Page" selected

Then go to your Facebook developer account , select your app and

4. Go to Settings > Advanced
5. In the App Pages part you should see "select from existing" button where you can select and link your existing Facebook page

Done :)